# Why pre ico sites have login pages

Tags: presale

I have seen many pre ico sites needs a login page to be created . Would like to know why is that created and where do they store the information ?

Answer (score 1):

Many teams create a presale website for people to signup so they can get info from the potential contributors, and also as a means to do the corresponding KYC/AML to comply with regulation.

Most time, the info these sites collect are stored off-chain. They even take contributions in BTC, ETH or fiat and then when the smart contract is in place they use the info they collected to distribute the tokens bought during the presale.

Comment: Do they also create account for the registered user ? Like coinbase wallet etc